# How to install Ruby and Net::IMAP on Windows?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I need to get started with Net::IMAP to write a Ruby script on Windows, so I've got the RubyInstaller for windows, but how do I install the IMAP gem? How do I setup my dev environment to write and run scripts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[As I see](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/net/imap/rdoc/classes/Net/IMAP.html) Net::Imap is a standart class and you don't need to install any gems.

Just install Ruby, launch your the favorite editor and try examples.

```
irb(main):005:0> require 'net/imap'
=> true
irb(main):006:0> imap = Net::IMAP.new('mail.example.com')
```